# WKWebView does not detect the video URL of Instagram, Facebook, and Netflix video

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, instagram, wkwebview

I want to detect the video URL of Facebook video and Instagram video but WKWebView gives a YouTube video URL. I already used WKWebView navigation delegate but it does not give the video URL.

```swift
webView!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] {
        print("observeValue \(key)") // url value
    }
}
```

Comment: facebook add a extra security layer to hide downloadable url.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have restrictions or limitations on embedding or playing videos outside of their official app or website. They use various mechanisms to prevent unauthorised access to their content.